# Why does my mesh flatten on the X-axis in the game engine?

Tags: game-engine, objects, armature

I have a little lizard with a bone structure. Currently it has no animation and no game logic set. However, when pushing <kbd>P</kbd>, in game logic mode on the mesh, the mesh renders as a very squished version of itself, squished along the x-axis.

Also, none of the armature movements are visible, instead it's just what it was at default.

[image: Not Squished]

After pressing <kbd>P</kbd>, I get this:

[image: Squished]

Comment: Try selecting your object and your armature and pressing CTRL-A > Apply Scale.

Comment: Could you attach the blend-file.

Comment: I don't know of a way to attach files. @CharlesL Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: @Jamil [pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) is a good way for files under 30MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> -> *Apply Scale*. This will set scale of both objects to *1.0, 1.0, 1.0*.

Before you applied the scale, you must have scaled the objects along the X-Axis at one point. This will change the dimensions of the object, but the scale will be something like: *5.0, 1.0, 1.0*. This won't change much in the 3D view, but BGE will reset all scales to 1.0 which (as you noticed) causes issues.